# How to create a "pointer-like" class, easily exposing functions of member?

Tags: c#

What I am trying to do is find the most elegant way to create a "pointer-like" class for a specific object/class type that I have in a project.

What I mean is a little confusing without an example.  Take this really simple class:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    private string _name;
    public string GetName() { return _name; }
    public void SetName(string name) { _name = name; }
}
```

I want to create a second class which is like a pointer to it like this:

```
public class MyClassPtr
{
    private MyClass _obj;
    public bool IsValid = false;

    public MyClassPtr(MyClass obj) { _obj = obj; IsValid = true; }

    public void InvalidatePtr()
    {
        IsValid = false;
        obj = null;
    }

    // SOME MAGIC HERE?
}
```

**The challenge**:  The key is that I want to elegantly have `MyClassPtr` provide an interface to all of the public methods/members in `MyClass` *without* writing wrappers and/or accessors around each method/member.

I know that I could do this:

```
public class MyClassPtr
{
    public string GetName() { return _obj.GetName(); }
    ...
}
```

But that's what I want to avoid.  **Is there some fundamental abstraction that I don't know of that I can apply to MyClassPtr to allow it to easily re-expose the methods/members in `MyClass` directed through `_obj`**?  I do NOT want `MyClassPtr` to inherit `MyClass`.  Should `MyClassPtr` be a type instead, and some trick with accessors to expose the methods/members of `MyClass`?

---

**Edit:** More context on why I am looking for such a design through an example.  Here is the overall goal.  Imagine a platform that parses through data about people and when it finds information about a person, it creates an instance of `Person` with that information.  You could get a handle to that person like:

```
Person person1 = platform.GetPerson(based_on_data);
```

Now, imagine the platform had two instances of `Person` that it thought were different people, but all of a sudden information came in that strongly suggested those two instances actually refer to the same person.  So, the platform wants to merge the instances together in to a new object, let's call it `personX`.

Now, floating around in the platform someone had a copy of one of those two instances that got merged, which was `person1`.  What I want to do is on-the-fly replace `person1` with `personX`. Literally, I want `person1==personX` to be true, NOT just that they are two different objects with the same data.  This is important since the platform could make a change to `personX` and unless the two objects are literally equal, a change to `personX` would not be automatically reflected in `person1`.

Since I can't on-the-fly replace `person1` with `personX` I had that idea that I wouldn't give direct access to `Person`, instead I would give access to `PersonPtr` which the platform (on-the-fly) can change what `Person` it is pointing to.  This would insurance that once `person1ptr` gets updated to point to `personX`, if a change is made in `personX` it will be seen in `person1ptr`

Comment: No, there isn't, the closest you can get is either to generate the source code at compile time or generate the class in memory at runtime. If you told us why you need/want this, perhaps a more concrete answer can be given. For instance, would a simple property holding the underlying reference work for you? It would be `yourClassPtr.Value.Method()` instead of `yourClassPtr.Method()`. Also, `MyClassPtr` *is* a type.

Comment: Remoting proxies might works with some effort.

Comment: And come to think of it, `DynamicObject` might as well.

Comment: Please explain your higher level goals with this. The current idea looks like bad design.

Comment: The downside of DynamicObject is that there would be no guidance as to what members are available.  To a programmer trying to use the object, they'd have no easy view of what members there are, right?

Comment: Correct. And with the interface approach, you can only expose those things present in an interface, even if the type exposes more public members. Again, *why* do you want this? Perhaps there are better ways?

Comment: What's the interface approach?  Can you explain it?  Will the interface allow me to apply it to MyClassPtr somehow without having to implement each thing in the interface in MyClassPtr?

Comment: Interfaces and remoting proxies, not going to be pretty. Not even sure it will be possible, but there's a bit of work ahead of you if you want to go down that route.

Comment: Why is inheritance not an option? If you make the MyClass inherit from an interface the you can expose the interface as public in MyClassPtr

Comment: I see, Lasse.  Van, how do you do that exactly?  MyClass implements the interface, and then how do I expose it via MyClassPtr but direct it through the `_obj` member?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen also, I get the `yourClassPtr.Value.Method()` but what I also want to do is protect from a caller getting access to Value directly so that it can't gain a direct reference to it and have a copy of it

Comment: Add a public property to MyClassPtr that exposes the _obj (MyClass) as a get only (or private set). But I do believe that normal polymorphism is the better option.

Comment: I agree with DrKoch. It seems like you have some broader goal here, and are asking for help with a specific concept you _think_ could solve that goal. But you will get better help if you ask for help with the goal. This "pointer" idea seems poorly conceived. As an example, please explain why you can't just use a reference to a `MyClass` object directly, with the reference being `null` being your "not valid" indication.

Comment: OK, I edited the original post adding more context on why I am looking for this design.  I hope this helps clarify.

Comment: @DrKoch done... added overall concept and goals

Comment: Fine, from your detailed explanation its clear you need one level of indirection. But why do you not want to implement all methods and properties once again as wrappers which simply call the methods/properties of the encapsulated `person`?

Comment: If I understand your edit correctly, it would seem that `person1 = personX` would be sufficient (unless you've overloaded operator=), because MyClass is a reference type, and so person1 and personX are *already* pointers and can be assigned "on the fly". Is there some reason this would be insufficient?

Comment: @Esoteric OP says he does not have access to all the pointers that need to change *but* he has access to all the _wrapper_ classes.

Comment: @DrKoch:  It's just cumbersome.  The actual class has a lot of methods and members.  Then, I must always make sure that anything added or removed from the base class gets updated to the pointer.  Any time they go out of sync, it causes a problem.

Comment: Swapping the underlying object while other code is in the middle of an operation could result in that code using partially outdated information. It's not only easier to create a `Reference<Person>` class that exposes a `Person` property, it may also be safer, because other code can store that person in a local variable and work with it without having to take unexpected changes into account.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Let me clarify for you on top of what @DrKoch said.  Think of it like this.  You ask the platform a question like "Give me the person whose name is X" and it gives you back an instance `person1`.  Now, you have a reference to that instance.  All of a sudden, the platform merges and there is `personX`.  How does the platform all of a sudden change your local reference `person1`?  It can't just insert a `person1=personX` ... it has no access to `person1`

Comment: @PieterWitvoet could you give a brief signature of what that class looks like?  I'm trying to understand your suggestion

Comment: `class Reference<T> { public T Value; }` - code that operates on a `Person` would receive a `Reference<Person>`, store its `Value` in a local variable and work with that variable until it's done. Still seems a bit brittle to me, because it's so easy to just use that `Value` property...

Comment: It sounds like you should just use interfaces instead of concrete classes, then you have much more freedom to wrap and mix and match things behind the scenes. As long as you're dealing with concrete types, you're left with magic, and magic looks simple when using it, but is usually quite hard to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You could of course use something like

```
public class MyClassWrapper
{
    MyClass _obj;
    public MyClassWrapper(MyClass obj)
    {
        _obj = obj; 
    }

    public void Invoke(Action<MyClass> action)
    {
        action(_obj);
    }

    public U Invoke<U>(Func<MyClass, U> func)
    {
        return func(_obj);
    }

    public void ChangeTo(MyClass obj)
    {
        _obj = obj;
    }
}
```

Given your class looks like

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Example:

```
var person1 = new MyClass { Name = "Instance1" };
var person2 = new MyClass { Name = "Instance2" };

var wrapper = new MyClassWrapper(person1);

wrapper.Invoke(x => x.Name += "original");
var x = wrapper.Invoke(x => x.Name); // Instance1original

wrapper.ChangeTo(person2);

var y = wrapper.Invoke(x => x.Name); // Instance2
```

but it has a major drawback: you can't access members directly, so you can't bind the data (to a `DataTable` or a `Control`).

It would be better to implement all members of your class also in your wrapper class. If you're afraid changes in your class will be forgotten to be implemented in your wrapper, just use an interface:

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyClassWrapper: IMyClass
{
    MyClass _obj;
    public MyClassWrapper(MyClass obj)
    {
        _obj = obj; 
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _obj.Name; }
        set { _obj.Name = value; }
    }
}
```

Note that regardless which approach you use, you'll have to always keep a reference to the wrapper instance to actually change the underlying instance (using something like `static` aside).

Also, changing the underlying instance of such a wrapper without telling the component using it that it changed don't seem to be a good idea. Maybe your system is simple enough to get away with a wrapper; that's something you have to decide for yourself.

Maybe your wrapper should simply have an `Invalid` flag (and/or use an event to signal a change of the underlying object.). Once the underlying object is merged, it is set to `true` and each member access should throw an exception. This would force the component using the wrapper to deliberately react to changes and to reload the data from your service.

All in all, I think using such a wrapper will just clutter up your code and be error prone (just imagine adding multithreading to the mix). Think twice if you really need this wrapper.

Why not just simply ask your service for a new instance of your class everytime you use it (the service can simply use a cache)? Sure, you can't prevent that someone somewhere keeps a reference; but at least you'll keep your sanity.